# Wi-Fi speed is substantially less than my router speed

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet, speed, speedtest

I recently had my speed increased to 250Mbps by my ISP. When I checked it with a number of speed checkers using an Ethernet cable it was indeed correct. However when I tried it on Wi-Fi sitting next to the router it barely reached 50Mbps. I tried it with two laptops and my mobile: Still the same results. I know and expected there to be loss in speed for various reasons but this discrepancy seems abnormally high. My router supplied by my ISP is a Virgin Media Hub 3 VMDG500. I've tried resetting it, to no avail. My ISP is of the opinion that as I'm getting the full 250 Mbps, that their end is ok. While 50Mbps is generally OK, I'm paying for 250Mbps. Any advice  would be of great value. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure your devices have an AC or AX wireless NIC.  Less will be slower. Also even today's fast NICs do not yet match Ethernet speeds.

Comment: 54Mbit is approx wifi-G speed. 802.11n can be as slow as around 70, but higher with more antennas so unfortunately, "wireless n" does not fully specify the max speed of the device. I don't see VMDG500, but this one is VMDG505: ( http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Virgin_Media_Super_Hub_3 ) and it is wireless n/g/b

Comment: What is your laptop's Wi-Fi hardware capable of? It doesn't matter if your wireless router supports some fancy new high-speed flavor of Wi-Fi; if your laptop doesn't support the same thing, the wireless router can't use that new fast technology when talking to your laptop, because your laptop wouldn't be able to understand it. So you'll need to give us the details of the Wi-Fi hardware in your laptop if you want us to be able to calculate realistic performance expectations.

Comment: Also note that "Wi-Fi 5" or "11n" alone is not enough. The number of spatial streams is the single most critical information. Your cell phone almost certainly supports only one. // Please provide the exact make and model of the Wi-Fi cards in both laptops, you can see it in Device Manager on Windows.

Comment: thanks John, Daniel and other experts for your help. It seems my laptop is outdated, so you'r correct and thanks again                             Mike

Answer (score 0):

Wifi is shared spectrum. This means that the magic numbers they quote for wifi speed are more about total bandwidth available, not maximum bandwidth available to connections running on all the nodes.

As an example, lets say the Router says "WiFi 7+++EXTREME ULTRA has 2000Mb/s performance" And then you have 8 machines on the WiFi. If they are all working at the same time, they will average out to 2000/8 as their average speed.

The rest of the issue is neighbors. They share the same spectrum. So while they may not be connected to your router/AP, they are operating in the same frequencies. And being shared, this means their use limits your use, it's like having lots of people in the same room all talking at once. People have to take turns to make sure you can actually understand them.

This is all pretty high level and doesn't get too deep into the implementation details, but the ultimate result of all of this is, WiFi is going to be WAY slower than wired, not much you can do about that because that's how it's designed

Comment: This is literally how wifi works. But sure, downvote a correct answer?

Comment: This does not answer OP's problem but is only general commentary on Wi-Fi. Also, most stations are idle most of the time, so "divide by number of stations" does not lead to helpful results.

Comment: It can contribute to WiFi not performing well. I'm on 100Mbit and I get points in the day when I comfortably pull 12MB/s and others where I do not. General advice is general.